# How to change date in JTCalendar from different month without changing the week

Tags: ios, objective-c, jtcalendar

My question will be clearly understood if you first see the picture:
In the first image, the date selected was March 2

[image: First Image]

But when I try to select the 28 or 29 of February, instead of staying in the same week, it moves to the previous week.Please look at the second image.

[image: Second Image]

How can I avoid that?
Here are some of codes from the framework module itself:

```
- (void)viewDidScroll
{
if(self.contentSize.width <= 0){
    return;
}

CGSize size = self.frame.size;

switch (_pageMode) {
    case JTCalendarPageModeFull:

        if(self.contentOffset.x < size.width / 2.){
            [self loadPreviousPage];
        }
        else if(self.contentOffset.x > size.width * 1.5){
            [self loadNextPage];
        }

        break;
    case JTCalendarPageModeCenter:

        break;
    case JTCalendarPageModeCenterLeft:

        if(self.contentOffset.x < size.width / 2.){
            [self loadPreviousPage];
        }

        break;
    case JTCalendarPageModeCenterRight:

        if(self.contentOffset.x > size.width / 2.){
            [self loadNextPage];
        }

        break;
}

[_manager.scrollManager updateMenuContentOffset:(self.contentOffset.x / self.contentSize.width) pageMode:_pageMode];
}

- (void)loadPreviousPage
{
    NSDate *nextDate = [_manager.delegateManager dateForPreviousPageWithCurrentDate:_leftView.date];

// Must be set before chaging date for PageView for updating day views
self->_date = _leftView.date;

UIView<JTCalendarPage> *tmpView = _rightView;

_rightView = _centerView;
_centerView = _leftView;

_leftView = tmpView;
_leftView.date = nextDate;

[self updateMenuDates];

JTCalendarPageMode previousPageMode = _pageMode;

[self updatePageMode];

CGSize size = self.frame.size;

switch (_pageMode) {
    case JTCalendarPageModeFull:

        _leftView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
        _centerView.frame = CGRectMake(size.width, 0, size.width, size.height);
        _rightView.frame = CGRectMake(size.width * 2, 0, size.width, size.height);

        if(previousPageMode == JTCalendarPageModeFull){
            self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.contentOffset.x + size.width, 0);
        }
        else if(previousPageMode ==  JTCalendarPageModeCenterLeft){
            self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.contentOffset.x + size.width, 0);
        }

        self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(size.width * 3, size.height);

        break;
    case JTCalendarPageModeCenter:
        // Not tested

        _leftView.frame = CGRectMake(- size.width, 0, size.width, size.height);
        _centerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
        _rightView.frame = CGRectMake(size.width, 0, size.width, size.height);

        self.contentSize = size;

        break;
    case JTCalendarPageModeCenterLeft:

        _leftView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
        _centerView.frame = CGRectMake(size.width, 0, size.width, size.height);
        _rightView.frame = CGRectMake(size.width * 2, 0, size.width, size.height);

        self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.contentOffset.x + size.width, 0);
        self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(size.width * 2, size.height);

        break;
    case JTCalendarPageModeCenterRight:

        _leftView.frame = CGRectMake(- size.width, 0, size.width, size.height);
        _centerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
        _rightView.frame = CGRectMake(size.width, 0, size.width, size.height);

        self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(size.width * 2, size.height);

        break;
}

// Update dayViews becuase current month changed
[_rightView reload];
[_centerView reload];

if(_manager.delegate && [_manager.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(calendarDidLoadPreviousPage:)]){
    [_manager.delegate calendarDidLoadPreviousPage:_manager];
}
}
```

Comment: I am also using JTCalendar, but i am not facing any issue like you mentioned. I found one thing is it is moving to previous month. It looks correct.

Comment: But if I want date 28 or 29 in the above image,how can i see it? (I have chosen 29 date in the second image)

Comment: It is displaying the month as Feb correctly. But it is showing the last full week of Feb!! Getting?

Comment: you are using month view or week view? I used before 6 months, i couldn't understand from your code sorry.

Comment: I am using week view. But in a week, if there are two month dates, on selecting a date of any of that month, does not show that week correctly. Instead it moves right or left according to our selection.